# Foreign key from events table 1-1 0r many?

Tags: database-schema

I'm likely overthinking a problem here and may well get downvoted but I'm prepared to take the hit. I'm building my first schema in a data warehouse.

2 tables: events and contacts:

```
events(id(pk), cid, other, fields, here)
contacts(id (pk), cid(fk), other, fields, here)
```

Someone visits our website and registers. A line item is generated in events column "id" and a "cid" for contacts is generated. A new record is added to contacts.

I have two questions:

1. Can I make the primary key of contacts cid? Thus the primary key is also a foreign key?
2. I'm using MySQL Workbench to create the schema. When I create the contacts table I am able to set the foreign key of cid and the cardinality as either 1-1 or 1-many. From the point of view of contacts table, is the relationship 1-1 or to many? There will only ever be 1 cid record in contacts but if that user does multiple things (like receive an email from us etc) they will appear multiple times in events table. So, logically 1-many. But when creating this in Workbench the relation line appears as though it's a 1-many relation with the many part being at contacts, not the other way around as desired. It should be the other way around?

What is the relationship between events.cid and contacts.cid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user's registration results in a single `contact_` record while each user visit to the web site (each Session started) results in an `event_` record belonging to that user’s `contact_` record, then you have a One-To-Many relationship.

```
`contact_` = parent table (the One)
`event_` = child table (the Many)
```

Notice how I boiled down that relationship into a single sentence. That should be your goal when doing analysis work to determine table structure.

Relationships are almost always defined as a link from a primary key on parent table to a foreign key on a child table.

How you define the [primary key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) is up to you. First decide whether you want a [natural key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) or a [surrogate key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). In my experience a natural key never works out as the values always eventually change.

If using a surrogate key, decide what type. The usual choices are an integer tied to an automatically incrementing sequence generator, or a [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid). If ever [federating data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) with other databases or systems then UUID is the way to go. If using an integer, decide on size, with [32-bit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) integers handling a total of 2-4 billion records. A [64-bit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) integer can track 18 quintillion records.

The foreign key in child table is simply a copy of its assigned parent’s primary key value. So the foreign key must have same data type as that parent primary key.

If a particular parent record owns multiple records in the child table, each of those child records will carry a copy of that parent’s primary key. So if the user Susan has five events, her primary key value appears once in the `contact_` table and that same value appears five times in the `event_` table stored in the foreign key column.

If `cid` uniquely identifies each `contact_` record amongst all the other `contact_` records, then you have a primary key. No need to define another.

[image: ERD diagram using crows feet, for contact_ & event_ tables]

Comment: Hi @Basil thanks for the thorough response. I'll use contact.cid as primary key in contact table which will then be a foreign key in events table. When I posted my question I think I had things in reverse. In my mind the event happened first, and on the back of the initial event a cid is generated resulting in a new record in contact so from that pov I thought of event table as parent.

Comment: Regarding account creation: **Mark the particular "event_" record**. Perhaps the "event_" table has a column of "type_" in which you store "account creation". Or columns of "summary_" and "detail_" where "summary_" contains "account creation" phrase and "detail_" contains various other info such as date-time, their IP address, or whatever. If very important, add a Boolean column "account_creation_" on "event_", perhaps indexed. In other words, account creation is not special, it is just one of several types of events that can happen, such as "email sent", "bill paid", "tweet posted".

Comment: If you have a business rule that says creating a "contact_" row *always* involves creating at least one "event_" row marked as "account creation", then the [crows feet](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~bernatja/crowsfoot.html) in the diagram should be changed. The diagram says: Each "contact_" row can have *zero* or more "event_" children. But with that business rule it should be: Each "contact_" row can have *one* or more "event_" children (never zero).

Comment: Hi @Basil OK this is great thanks. Yes there will be an event_type field and having an account creation event sounds really obvious now so I can just filter on that for analysis. Again, this is my first schema! Regarding "crow's feet" in SQL Workbench this appears to be showing with a bar so I believe that does imply 1 or more

Comment: Crows foot notation was never standardized afaik. So variations exist. I prefer single bar to mean "one and only one" while others use a double bar. Presumably in a double-bar the first bar replaces the zero in zero+bar that means "zero or one" as seen my comment’s link.